# One Shard with Multiple Mongos

Tags: mongodb, web-applications, routes, ubuntu-12.04, sharding

Can we have this type of configuration?

Two server running the following things each-

```
1.Mongo Config Server.
2.Mongo Router.
3.Application.
```

Total 4 EC2 servers-

1. First Server-Running the web application & mongos.
2. Second Server-Running the web application & mongos.
3. Third Server-Running the First Shard with complete DB(Say for
   example Demo).
4. Forth Server-Running The Second Shard with complete DB(Say for
   example Demo).

Both the Mongos should point to one shard named Shard1?

Comment: Where would the shard be? You havent listed it? Can you tell us how you plan to distribute the applications on the two servers?

Comment: Yes, both mongos will point to shard1

Comment: You cannot have 2 config servers. You must have 3. Run the mongos and the application on the same machines, as you are planning to. The mongos are configured to point at the config db's. Then you add the shards using sh.addShard on one mongos, and proceed to shard the database and add sharded collections. Neither shard will have a "complete DB", by definition of sharding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, You can have multiple mongos instances running against a single shard. Think of the mongos instances as clients for the sharded cluster which have to run as a daemon process in order to keep metadata and heartbeats up to date.

*Edit*: as for having a complete DB, this is only possible for a single DB. You can have one DB on shard1 and the other DB on shard2, for example. but you can never have a single complete DB on two shards. To achieve the goal of having db1 on shard1 and db2 on shard2, you simply make the respective shard the primary shard of the respective database and don't shard any collection. Please read [the docs for the movePrimary command](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/movePrimary/) for details.

*A bit OOT:*

However, running a single config server is strongly advised against, and for a good reason. If the single config server goes down or gets corrupted, your cluster will be impossible to use - and recreating the sharded cluster will not an easy task to be done. And it's going to be a lengty process. So please, use three config servers.*